# Testing .xap on windows phone 8, without registration

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xap

I have got a .xap file, i mailed it and opened it in my windows phone 8.
It gives me company app error.

Also i tried it with deployment in visual studio, it runs fine with emulator but problem with device(zune software not installed) whereas i have installed it and it is not detecting the device.

My question is that can we test an application without any company registration on windows phone device, just for testing purpose.
I have got an microsoft account.

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy the XAP, but you must unlock the device first.

Fortunately, it's now a free process, you don't need a devcenter account anymore. The only limitation is that you can deploy only two applications at a time (when deploying a third application, you must remove a previous one).

The procedure is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: **Partially true.** You can sideload up to two apps on a free account. Details here: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/08/06/making-it-easier-to-get-started-with-windows-phone-app-studio-beta-simplified-phone-registration-support-options-amp-more-payout-markets.aspx

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Indeed, only one device but two applications. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Does this apply to Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

I think Beta testing will help u.We can upload a build as beta version to the market for testing purposes.Have a look on the below link.
[Beta Version in WindowsPhone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the live test of phonegap (as you said you use it) will be great for you. Please see http://app.phonegap.com/ for more information.

Comment: Excellent, why have I not heard about this before now?? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check unsigned apps up to two apps on a free account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can u please tell me how to sign xap file which is obtained from phonegap.

Comment: **False.** You can test unsigned XAP files (aka sideload them) on a physical device.

Comment: You can register 1 physical device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual studio installed, search for "Application deployment" from start or Run XapDeploy.exe. Test unsigned .XAP