# Sideloading a single app on WP8 for free?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sideloading

I have a WP8 phone, and a Windows 8 PC with Visual Studio 2012.

If I have developed an app I wish to load and test on my physical WP8 phone, what additional costs can I expect?

Note that I don't wish to upload it to Windows Store, I just want to use it on my phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing .xap on windows phone 8, without registration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159325/testing-xap-on-windows-phone-8-without-registration)

Comment: It, indeed, is a duplicate of said question. I wish I knew how to search for the question.